# Filtration infinitesimal glance into the future

Tags: independence, infinitesimals, measurable-functions, filtrations

For the filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\} $ we defined for $t \geq 0$ the filtration 
 $\mathcal{F}_t^+:=\cap_n~ \mathcal{F}_{t+\frac{1}{n}}$.

There is one equality I don't understand. For $A \in \mathcal{F}_0^+$ we say $E_x[1_A] = E_x[1_A|\mathcal{F}_0^+]$

Why does this equality hold? Is $1_A$ independent of $\mathcal{F}_0^+$?

Comment: I don't think this is true for a general filtration. In fact the stated equality is true for all $A \in \mathcal F_0^{+}$ iff $\mathcal F_0^{+}$ is trivial in the sense every set in it has probability $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Yes, $A \in \mathcal{F}_0^+$. But why does this equality hold for the trivial sigma-algebra?